# How to copy all records and add some changes in the same table in OracleDB

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, create-table

I would like to copy all records into the same table with some changes.
Is someone tell me a good way?

I tried to this. but Not Ended error happen.
How can I fixt it?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "TestScheme".tmp_history FROM history;
UPDATE tmp_history set
birthday  =  ADD_MONTHS(birthday,-24),
TRD_SEQ = replace('Stack','poo','pee')
INSERT INTO history SELECT * FROM  "TestScheme".tmp_history
```

ORA-00933:"SQL command not properly ended"
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table tmp_history as
  select * from history
  where card_no = 'XXXX3';

update tmp_history set
  birthday = add_months(birthday, -24),
  trd_seq = replace('Stack', 'poo', 'pee');

insert into history 
  select * from tmp_history;
```

Comment: The only reason would be the fact that no rows contain CARD_NO whose value is equal to XXXX3.

Comment: original table contains XXX3